# How can I display data from database in my listview one by one?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

I am new in developing apps. I try to create reservation system.

I would like to retrieve data and display on listview as shown below;

[image: here]

name should be under the textview for name and phone for phone etc..

```
public class Resden extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference depref;
    FirebaseDatabase fdata;
    TextView namev, phonev, emailv, arrv, depv, paxv, ratev, roomtypev;
    Guest newguest;

    ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resden);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lviewy);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        fdata = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        depref = fdata.getReference("Guests");
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        depref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                                             for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                 String name = (String) childSnapShot.child("Guests").getValue();
                                                 String phone = (String) childSnapShot.child("phone").getValue();
                                                 String email = (String) childSnapShot.child("email").getValue();
                                                 String arriving = (String) childSnapShot.child("arriving").getValue();
                                                 String departure = (String) childSnapShot.child("departure").getValue();
                                                 String pax = (String) childSnapShot.child("pax").getValue();
                                                 String rate = (String) childSnapShot.child("rate").getValue();
                                                 String roomtype = (String) childSnapShot.child("roomtype").getValue();

                                                 list.add(name);
                                                 list.add(phone);
                                                 list.add(email);
                                                 list.add(arriving);
                                                 list.add(departure);
                                                 list.add(pax);
                                                 list.add(rate);
                                                 list.add(roomtype);



                                             }

                                         }
```

and this is my activity

I also created Guest class with getter and setter..

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the **arrayAdapter** inside **onChildAdded**.

```
public class Resden extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference depref;
FirebaseDatabase fdata;
TextView namev, phonev, emailv, arrv, depv, paxv, ratev, roomtypev;
Guest newguest;

ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resden);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lviewy);

    fdata = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    depref = fdata.getReference("Guests");


    depref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                                         for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                             String name = (String) childSnapShot.child("Guests").getValue();
                                             String phone = (String) childSnapShot.child("phone").getValue();
                                             String email = (String) childSnapShot.child("email").getValue();
                                             String arriving = (String) childSnapShot.child("arriving").getValue();
                                             String departure = (String) childSnapShot.child("departure").getValue();
                                             String pax = (String) childSnapShot.child("pax").getValue();
                                             String rate = (String) childSnapShot.child("rate").getValue();
                                             String roomtype = (String) childSnapShot.child("roomtype").getValue();

                                             list.add(name);
                                             list.add(phone);
                                             list.add(email);
                                             list.add(arriving);
                                             list.add(departure);
                                             list.add(pax);
                                             list.add(rate);
                                             list.add(roomtype);



                                         }

                                            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                                            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                                     }
```

.**addChildEventListener**(listener) **works async** so will be **always null** if you fill the adapter **outside** of the listener.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

:((

Comment: @OnurAslan i saw String name = (String) childSnapShot.child("Guests").getValue(); you have a child of "Guests" table called "Guests?", maybe there is the problem.

Comment: yes I thought that...I will change it and let you know..thanks again.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean dont know why is it a boolean ? though the others are string

Comment: something interesting..I can now display items on listview but when I scroll down it..crashs Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Thx Onur, Strange, is the same field(name) who is throwing the exception or is another one now?

Comment: name field but I fixed it . I used Recylerview instead :/ but it works now :) thanks again